# Sorry, Ubuntu has experienced an internal error. I use 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04

Whenever I boot Ubuntu, I get a message 'Sorry, Ubuntu has experienced an internal error' and when I click on 'continue' to send an error report, the pop-up disappears. I didn't face any problem til now. But now few problems like not being able to connect to a LAN network(through ethernet cable), ALT+F2 then r not restarting gnome and the sign-out icon between settings and power not working, have popped up.

Earlier I was using 16.04 and everything was working fine. I have recently upgraded my system to 18.04.

PS - Please do not flag the question as a duplicate because the other person who had the same problem specified NVIDIA but I am not sure what is wrong with mine.

Comment: Hello, please add your PC/laptop specs, if you had any applications that started at boot in 16.04 and if you have any now.

Comment: I am using Acer Aspire series with Intel  i5(7th gen), 8gb ram, 1 TB HD, NVIDIA 940MX and the clockspeed of processor is 2.5 GHz.

Comment: Blueman applet, Caffeine, Indicator netspeed-unity, mpd music player daemon, NVIDIA X server settings, snap user application autostart helper, SSH key agent, welcome(no description), Xtreme download manager. This is the list of all the applications that start up during boot.